# Eli throws five darts at a circular target, and each one lands within one of the four regions...

Tags: combinatorics

Eli throws five darts at a circular target, and each one lands within one of the four regions. The point-value of a dart landing in each region is indicated. What is the least score greater than five points that is not possible when the point-values of the five darts are added together?
[image]

Please don't give the answer, I want a hint, so I still gain something from this problem.

Comment: Are you comfortable using a computer approach?  What might the expansion of the polynomial $(x+x^2+x^4+x^6)^5$ represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can always waste extra darts if you have a score greater than $5$: If there’s a $6$, move it to $4$ and add a $2$; if there’s a $4$, move it to $2$ and add another $2$; if there’s a $2$, move it to $1$ and add another $1$; if there aren’t any of these, all the darts are on the $1$s so the score is at most $5$. So we can replace the problem by the slightly simpler problem which numbers can be represented with **at most** five darts.

Note that you can use $1,2,4$ as binary digits. Since the next value is $6$, not $8$, you only need to use $1,2,4$ to get up to $5$ before adding another $6$. Note that the binary representations of the numbers up to $5$ contain at most two $1$s. What’s the first number that can’t be represented in this way? It’s then straightforward to see that it can’t be represented in any other way either.

Answer (score 1):

So the result is $$k= a\cdot 1+b\cdot 2+c\cdot 4+d\cdot 6, \;\;\;(*)$$

where $a+b+c+d=5$ and $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{N}_0$.

Now you have to find a minimal $k$ not possible to express with $(*)$.